# Busqueda en pilas C++

Tags: c++, csv, pilas

Hola a todos estoy tratando de implementar un programa con pilas el cual extrae los datos de un .CSV
el contenido del archivo viene de la siguiente forma :

2254832,Mark,06/12/2020,59595956
1651515,Frank,08/11/2019,18182878
5163433,Louis,06//10/2020,15152626
1651515,Frank,02/11/2019,129596256

Ya logre crear la pila sin embargo con la función de búsqueda ingreso el id a buscar(el numero primero de cada línea yo lo tengo como ID en el programa)y si lo encuentra lo imprime las veces que este el numero, lo que yo intento hacer es que aparte de mostrarme las veces que se encuentra que me imprima a la vez los demás datos que están en esa línea, dejo una foto de muestra.

por ejemplo quisiera que me mostrara al buscar id (1651515):

Id:1651515 Frank 08/11/2019 18182878
Id:1651515 Frank 02/11/2019 12959625

pero como se logra ver en la foto solo he logrado imprimir el ID.

Alguien me pudiera apoyar a indicarme como lo puedo hacer gracias.

### [image: Salida de pantalla]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// DEFINITION
struct Node {
    intmax_t ID;
    string name;
    string date;
    string number;
   // intmax_t content;
    Node *next;
};
/*
struct Node{
    intmax_t content;
    Node *next;
};*/

typedef Node *ptrNode;
vector <Node> a;

void addstack( ptrNode *ptrtop, intmax_t n ){

    ptrNode ptrNew;
    ptrNew = new Node;

    if ( ptrNew != NULL  ) {
        ptrNew->ID = n;
        ptrNew->next = *ptrtop;
        *ptrtop = ptrNew;
    }

    cout << "\tPerson with ID: [" << n<<"] found"<<endl;
}

void searchdata(ptrNode cursor)
{
     vector <Node> a;
     ptrNode aux;
    if( cursor == NULL ) {
        cout << "\n\t\nThe stack is empty\n";
        return;
    }
    intmax_t n;
    bool found=false;
    cout<<"\n\nEnter id to search: "<<endl;
    cin>>n;

    while( cursor != NULL ) {
            if(n==cursor->ID){
                cout<<"\tLocated id: "<<cursor->ID<<"\n";
                 cout<<"\tNombre: "<<aux->name<<"\n";
                found =true;
            }
            cursor = cursor->next;
        }
        if(found==false){
        cout << "id not found."<<endl;
    }
}
int main(){
Node *stack_ = NULL;
string namefile, line;
    cout << "Enter file name:" << endl;
    cin >> namefile;
    ifstream file;
    file.open(namefile.c_str());
    if(!file.is_open()) {
        cout << "File "<< namefile <<" not found." << endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    for (Node i;
        (file >> i.ID).ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), ',')
        && getline(file, i.name, ',')
        && getline(file, i.date, ',')
        && getline(file, i.number);
        )
    {
        a.push_back(i);
        cout<<"\n\nName: "<<i.name;
        cout<<"\nDate: "<<i.date;
        cout<<"\nNumber: "<<i.number;
        addstack( &stack_, i.ID );


    }
    searchdata( stack_);
    system("pause");
    file.close();

return 0;
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Luis. Espero estés bien. El problema ésta en la memoria: node del for no se guarda en el nodo del stack que usas en el resto del programa (ptrtop).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

struct Node {
    int ID;
    string name;
    string date;
    string number;
    Node *next;
};

typedef Node *ptrNode;

void addstack( ptrNode *ptrtop, Node i){
    ptrNode ptrNew;
    ptrNew = new Node;
    if ( ptrNew != NULL  ) {
        ptrNew->ID = i.ID;
        ptrNew->name = i.name;
        ptrNew->date = i.date;
        ptrNew->number = i.number;
        ptrNew->next = *ptrtop;
        *ptrtop = ptrNew;
    }
    cout << "\tPerson with ID: [" << i.ID <<"] found"<<endl;
}

void searchdata(ptrNode cursor)
{
    if( cursor == NULL ) {
        cout << "\n\t\nThe stack is empty\n";
        return;
    }
    int n;
    bool found=false;
    cout<<"\n\nEnter id to search: "<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    while( cursor != NULL ) {
            if(n==cursor->ID){
                cout<<"\tLocated id: "<<cursor->ID<<"\n";
                cout<<"\tNombre: "<<cursor->name<<"\n";
                cout<<"\tFecha: "<<cursor->date<<"\n";
                found = true;
            }
            cursor = cursor->next;
        }
        if(found==false){
        cout << "id not found."<<endl;
    }
}
int main(){
    Node *stack_ = NULL;
    string namefile, line;
    cout << "Enter file name:" << endl;
    cin >> namefile;
    ifstream file;
    file.open(namefile.c_str());
    if(!file.is_open()) {
        cout << "File "<< namefile <<" not found." << endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    for (Node i;
        (file >> i.ID).ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), ',')
        && getline(file, i.name, ',')
        && getline(file, i.date, ',')
        && getline(file, i.number);
        )
    {
        cout<<"\n\nName: "<<i.name;
        cout<<"\nDate: "<<i.date;
        cout<<"\nNumber: "<<i.number;
        addstack( &stack_, i);
    }
    searchdata(stack_);
    system("pause");
    file.close();

return 0;
}
```

Por cierto, escribe código limpio.
Recuerda aprender testing, orientación a objetos y patrones de diseño. Eso te convierte en un mejor desarrollador.

Comment: Te agradezco mucho la ayuda!